# Trigger Twilio studio flow using Zapier

Tags: facebook, twilio, webhooks, zapier, twilio-studio

What I need to do is to trigger a Twilio studio flow, when a new lead form facebook leads ads i generated.

Is this possible? if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: Try Zapier by creating a zap

Answer (score 0):

#### Both Twilio Studio and Zapier support webhooks

###### This can be accomplished using this flow.

1. Facebook Ad Generates Lead (This data is stored on a Google Sheet or Database)
2. Google Sheet or Database receives new record - from above (This activates a Zapier Webhook that points to Twilio)
3. Zapier webhook activates Twilio Studio Flow with Studio Webhook (You can send what ever data is needed in the Zapier webhook)
4. Twilio Studio Activates (Done)

| References | Check out these links for more info |
| --- | --- |
| [Twilio Studio Webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#triggering-flows) | Learn more about the twilio Studio Webhooks / API triggers. |
| [Zapier Webhook](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations) | The goal here to identify what you want to trigger the webhook - plenty of options |
| [What Are Webhooks](https://zapier.com/blog/what-are-webhooks/) | Zapier created a good blog on explaining webhooks |
| [Twilio Studio API Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-conduct-a-survey) | Twilio created a example studio flow of a survey that uses APIs / webhooks |